# Extra space before list items in a flexbox container

Tags: html, list, css, flexbox

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.menu
{
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.menu li::before
{
  content: "\2022";
}
```

Items 1 and 4 work fine but there is one extra space before items 2 and 3 (right after the bullet). I know that's because there is a new line in HTML for these items. However, everything works fine without the `ul.menu li::before` rule.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Does anyone have an idea how to get rid of the extra space and still preserve new lines in HTML? Some neat solution maybe, rather than just `ul.menu li a::before` (this one is not good, it makes the bullets clickable as well).

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2t85s6k0/)

P.S.: same problem appears even without `display: flex;` so it's obviously not flexbox-related.

Comment: This is basically the same issue: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *space* you see is a characteristic of all *inline elements* - just add `display: flex` to the `li` too.

See demo below and my [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r91j2b4k/):

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul.menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.menu li::before {
  content: "\2022";
}
ul.menu li {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice and short. Thank you, that's what I need! Brilliant is simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `<li>` for item2 and item3 in same line it will remove space.

Try this code. It works.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2t85s6k0/2/)

## HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

## CSS

```
body
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul.menu
{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.menu li::before
{
    content: "\2022";
}
```

Comment: Please read my question carefully: `how to get rid of the extra space and still preserve new lines in HTML?`